# Socket Error - OSError: [Errno 99] - Running Jupyter-notebook on remote host

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm working on a remote machine using SSH login. When trying to open the jupyter notebook in the virtual environment called `balancing_selection`, using the following command:

`jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8887`

I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
        return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
      File "/home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
        app.initialize(argv)
      File "</home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
      File "/home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
        return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1679, in initialize
        self.init_webapp()
      File "/home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1442, in init_webapp
        self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
      File "/home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
        sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
      File "/home/homap/miniconda3/envs/balancing_selection/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 174, in bind_sockets
        sock.bind(sockaddr)
    OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to specify the IP of your localhost (VM)

```
jupyter-notebook --no-browser --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8887
```

or

```
jupyter-notebook --no-browser --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8887  # all interfaces on host
```

It's also possible that your `/etc/hosts` file has `localhost` set incorrectly. The `localhost` should be pointed to the IPv4 address, and IPv6 should be created as a separate entry for the IPv6 loopback.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain    localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6  localhost6
```